# CSS 3 :Show button from the center

Tags: html, css

I have 2 buttons. when I click on the first button then it gets disappeared and 2nd button gets appeared. I want 2nd button to be appeared from the center. I mean it should expand/show it self from the center.

[You can check here the Open button for the output I want](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/c21307792a960e90d630440e09d308d7c854dac3/687474703a2f2f706574656c6164612e636f6d2f696d616765732f706c6164612d6c6f6164696e672d627574746f6e2e676966)

```css
.sending_btn{
  outline: none;
  width: 128px;
  height: 30px;
  animation: createBox .25s;

}
@keyframes createBox {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
      <button type="button" name="button" class="sending_btn b bg-white-only">Sending...</button>
```

Instead of scaling , I want to make it grow from the center.

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get with wrap your button inside a div and assign css center.

Remove `scale` and use `width` to get it.

just like following

With `width` animatation

```css
.center {
  text-align:center;
}
.sending_btn{
  outline: none;
  width: 128px;
  height: 30px;
  animation: createBox 1s;
  transform-origin:center center;
}
@keyframes createBox {
  from {
    width: 0;
    font-size:0px;
  }
  to {
    width: 128px;
    font-size:14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <button type="button" name="button" class="sending_btn b bg-white-only">Sending...</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, I dont' want this output. I want the button which is appearing should be appeared from the center.Have you check the link I have put in the question?

Comment: i want button to be expanding from center... have you check the **Open** button in the given link?

Comment: You can animate your width 0 to 128px.

Comment: how can I do ? i don't know the syntax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147899/discussion-between-rishi-and-lokesh-gupta).

Comment: Animating width is typically a bad idea, because there is no subpixel rendering. Use `scaleX(0)` and `scaleX(1)` instead :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function togglefun() {
  document.getElementById("btn1").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("btn2").style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('btn2').className = 'bg-white-only';


}
```

```css
.sending_btn {
  outline: none;
}

.bg-white-only {
  animation: createBox .25s;
}

.b2 {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes createBox {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" name="button" id="btn1" class="sending_btn b1 bg-white-only" onclick="togglefun()">Sending...</button>
<button type="button" name="button" id="btn2" class="sending_btn b2">second...</button>
```

Comment: Hello, I dont' want this output. I want the button which is appearing should be appeared from the center.Have you check the link I have put in the question?

Answer (score -1):

Enclose the HTML code of button in  tag

```
 <center><button type="button" name="button" class="sending_btn b bg-white-only">Sending...</button></center>
```

Comment: `<center>` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center), please don't use it.

Comment: Hello, I dont' want this output. I want the button which is appearing should be appeared from the center.Have you check the link I have put in the question?